Lightning Out: Uncaught ReferenceError: $A is not defined at lightning.out.delegate.js
I used Lightning out feature to embed a custom LWC in our company's website.
I have built the Aura Wrapper needed for the lightning out.
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:mainComponent"/>
</aura:application> 

I removed ltng:allowGuestAccess since we're always passing authenticated token in the script. We used JWT auth flow to get auth token from Salesforce.
To implement this in the external webpage, we put the HTML file below in an iframe.
sfdc-lightning-out.html

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
        <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
        <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
        
        <script src="https://YOURSITEDOMAIN/SITEURL/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>

    </head>
    
    <body onload="loadLightningOut()">

        <div data-lightning-out="true"></div>

        <script>

            function loadLightningOut() {

                try {

                    const appName = 'c:auraWrapper';
                    const componentName = 'c:mainComponent';
                    
                    const lightningEndpoint = 'https://YOURSITEDOMAIN/SITEURL/';

                    const targetElement = document.querySelector("[data-lightning-out]");
                    const componentAttributes = {};

                    const authToken = '<sfdc-token>';

                    $Lightning.use(
                            appName,
                            function() {
                                $Lightning.createComponent(
                                        componentName,
                                        componentAttributes,
                                        targetElement,
                                        function (cmp){
                                            console.log('lightning component created');
                                        }
                                );
                            },
                            lightningEndpoint,
                            authToken
                    );

                } catch(e) {
                    console.error("Error >> ", e);
                }

            }

        </script>
                 
    </body>

</html>

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

        <iframe 
            src="sfdc-lightning-out.html" 
            style="width:100%;height:900px;border:none;">
        </iframe>

    </body>

</html>

This index.html is the main page of the website.
Issue:
On the first page load, we are experiencing the Uncaught ReferenceError: $A is not defined issue as shown below.
Console tab

Network tab

But after you refresh the whole page, the Lightning out page works.
Both the LWC and the site that we used is still in Sandbox as we are still developing the feature.
We are currently stuck with this issue and any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

If the issue is still ongoing, it can be due to the enhanced domain, pls check My domain setting.

@KenanCe How do you figure that enhanced domains are a factor here? I'm pretty sure Salesforce forced everyone to enable it sometime last year, so it's not exactly like it could be disabled.
